# How to display a hasMany association

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm new to ember and I created a model like this :

```
# app/models/skill.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.hasMany('user')
});
```

I have this route :

```
# app/routes/skill.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    return this.store.find('skill', params.id);
  }
});
```

This router :

```
# app/router.js
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('users', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/'} );
    this.route('signup');
  });
  this.resource('skills', function() {
    this.route('index', { path: '/' });
  });
  this.resource('skill', { path: '/skills/:id' });
});

export default Router;
```

And this template :

```
# app/templates/skill.hbs
{{#link-to 'skills.index'}}Back{{/link-to}}
{{model.name}}
{{model.description}}

{{#each user in model.user}}
  {{user.nickname}}
{{/each}}
```

I simply want to have a list of users with their nicknames. This is the response from my api :

```
{
  "skills": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Ember",
    "description": "JS Framework",
    "link": "emberjs.com"
  },
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": null,
      "nickname": null,
      "bio": null,
      "created_at": "2015-06-21T10:40:34.555Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-21T10:40:34.555Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "test",
      "nickname": "dougui",
      "bio": "blabla",
      "created_at": "2015-06-21T10:40:50.493Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-21T10:40:50.493Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "email": null,
      "nickname": null,
      "bio": null,
      "created_at": "2015-06-21T20:51:29.546Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-21T20:51:29.546Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "email": null,
      "nickname": null,
      "bio": null,
      "created_at": "2015-06-21T20:55:11.163Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-21T20:55:11.163Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "email": null,
      "nickname": null,
      "bio": null,
      "created_at": "2015-06-21T20:55:51.231Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-21T20:55:51.231Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "email": "email",
      "nickname": "nickname",
      "bio": null,
      "created_at": "2015-06-22T00:01:47.089Z",
      "updated_at": "2015-06-22T00:01:47.089Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

There is all information about skill and users but nothing is shown.

Why my list is not rendered?

Thanks!

### Edit 1

Now, my api is sending this `{"skill":{"id":2,"name":"Rails","description":"test","user_ids":[2]}}`.

I have this model :

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  link: DS.attr('string'),
  users: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true })
});
```

I tried also with :

```
users: DS.hasMany('users', { async: true })
```

I don't know what to do. Is it possible to have an example with the current version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember data expects that you will give it a object called `skill` not `skills` (`skills` will be ok for requesting multiple skills, not one instance).

Next thing: your model expects `users` array in `skill` object. Right now you are sending it separately.

And last one... You have put full `users` object instead of just ids of these objects. In that case, you have to add flag `{embedded: 'always'}` to `users` property (read more [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin.html))